# I'm Having Difficulty Giving My Dog His Insulin Shots

Tags: dogs, medicines, diabetes

My dog is an 11 year old chihuahua mix. He was diagnosed with diabetes back in 2012. We have been giving him insulin shots twice a day, one in the morning and one at night since 2012. He visits the vet every year, some times twice a year to get checked up and see how his diabetes is going. At first we gave him 5 ml of insulin and just recently the vet put up his doze to 8 ml. We have been injecting him on his neck for the past 4 years. But now his neck has multiple little bumps where we frequently injected him in the past. The vet told us to start injecting him on his lower back area kind of by his tail, and he even demonstrated but it's really hard and I get really nervous. Also as I've tried to inject him in that new area, it seems that it hurts him and I can never get it right. This morning I tried to inject him on his neck again after a really long time and I drew blood accidently which really freaked me out since that has never happened before. Dealing with his diabetes has become really hard and I'm considering putting him down which is something I really don't want to do, I want him to die by natural causes. I want to continue fighting his diabetes along side him but I'm becoming hopeless. I scheduled an appointment with his vet next week and we will talk more about how to inject him and maybe even possibilities of putting him to sleep if there is no other way. Even though he's old he still seems fine I don't want to give up on him until I see he can't continue anymore. Please, I would really appreciate it if someone out there could share with me some detailed advice of where and how to inject my dog and how to make the experience less painful for him. Thank you.

Comment: Since it sounds like your dog lets you give him shots, he trusts you a lot. It's probably as uncomfortable for him as it would be for you, so continue to shower him with treats during the shot so it stays positive, but he'll let you know if it's ever painful (probably with teeth or growling at the needle).

Maybe ask the vet to watch you practice giving the shot without a needle so he can see your technique and give you some tips?

Comment: Insuline shots are subcutaneous, and can be given basically everywhere on the body. Humans typically just "pinch" their belly to get something like a "love handle" to inject into. Sometimes, rarely, you hit a vein but it doesn't matter. Just find a spot with loose skin on his body and do the injection.

Comment: Is it possible to administer insulin as a tablet or some such? I know that some humans with some types of diabetes can take tablets, but not all. Your veterinarian will have better information.